# (document).ready is a global scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Guys i have this function inside my script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function alert() {
      alert('AAAAAAAA');
    }
});
```

And i am trying to call here in my index.html:

```
$('.something').on('click', function() {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert();
});
```

But is showing my this error - alert is not defined.

But when i take off the document ready in the external script, the click handler will work. Why  is that?

The document ready is creating a separate scope?

Comment: You shouldn't use "alert" as name for a custom function, since alert is already a built-in function in javascript. Try to call it differently and don't forget to add "e" as a parameter in your click callback function.

Comment: You are missing a parameter in the call to alert() in $(".something", ....

Comment: @AdriánBolonio this is just an example, the real function is more complex them that, but the idea is the same.

Comment: It's not the `$(document).ready()` that is creating the scope, but the `function(){ }`!

Comment: Please ask only one question per post, I've removed the second one. Ask another one if you don't find your answer in [this blog post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html) - yes, your version is usually better than your teacher's.

Comment: ok, i am sorry @Bergi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `$(document).ready()` creates a new function scope (note the `function()` after the `.ready`), so when you call

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function alert() {
        alert('AAAAAAAA');
    }
});
```

`alert` is only defined within the `document.ready` block. There are two ways to solve this issue:

1. Define the function outside of the `document.ready` block:

   ```
   function customAlert() {
       alert('AAAAAAAA');
   }
   ```
2. Attach the function to the `window` object:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       window.customAlert = function() {
           alert('AAAAAAAA');
       };
   });
   ```

Comment: Please also advise not to use the second solution :-)

Comment: @Bergi There honestly isn't any practical difference between the first and the second solutions, so I don't see why it shouldn't be used.

Comment: "alert" is also a method defined by the browser in JavaScript and not all browsers will allow you to override it with your own functionality.

Comment: @mc10: Of course there is: the time at which the `customAlert` function is available. If you create it in the ready handler, you cannot call it before that.

Answer (score 1):

Include the click event into the document.ready

Check it here http://jsfiddle.net/fbrcm45q/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function showAlert() {
    alert('AAAAAAAA');
  }
  $('.something').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showAlert();
  });
});
```

Comment: i can't, cause the event must be in the html file, and the function must be in  an external file.

Comment: Try to take the function out of the document ready. Is a function, no need to render it once the document is fully loaded, right?

Comment: @DRX: The function declaration does not need to be inside the `$(document).ready` handler - but listening to the click events must!

Answer (score 0):

First of all e.preventDefault is a function so you have to add braces at the end:

```
e.preventDefault()
```

Second alert is a function in javascrpt, so you need to rename your function to something else, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function special_alert() {
      alert('AAAAAAAA');
    }
});
```

and:

```
$('.something').on('click', function() {
  e.preventDefault();
  special_alert();
});
```

Comment: get it, i will try this.

Comment: No need to rename `alert`. Putting it in a local scope is enough.

Comment: This doesn't actually fix the scoping error that results from a separate `document.ready` block.