# function is not defined error on upload file page

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to make html page for uploading a file. I created a upload.cgi for the process. And added below code to my html page:

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="https://gpstest.surveybook.net/upload/upload.cgi" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file_upload">Select a file:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" onchange="uploadFile()"><br>
</form>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    function uploadFile() {
        // Get the form element
        var form = document.getElementById('uploadForm');
        
        // Submit the form
        form.submit();
    }
})
</script>
```

It should upload when a file selected but i get error (in console) : "Uncaught ReferenceError: uploadFile is not defined"

Is it possible that i get this error because cant access to the upload.cgi, if not i am out of ideas and appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(document).ready is a global scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387331/document-ready-is-a-global-scope)

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to surround a function declaration with a ready event-listener, unless you want that function to be only accessible _within_ that event handler. Remove the jQuery `.ready()` listener and it should work fine.

Comment: Just remove $(document).ready , You don't need that here

Comment: i remove the $(document).ready(function(){}) now i get error "Uncaught TypeError: form is null"

Comment: I post the answer and put a sample alert  for make sure the function works

Answer (score 0):

The error "Uncaught ReferenceError: uploadFile is not defined" is occurring because the uploadFile function is defined inside the $(document).ready function, which makes it not accessible in the global scope. The onchange attribute in your HTML is trying to access uploadFile from the global scope, hence the error.

To fix this, you should move the uploadFile function outside of the $(document).ready function.

```js
<script>
    function uploadFile() {
        // Get the form element
        var form = document.getElementById('uploadForm');
        
        // Submit the form
        form.submit();
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Other jQuery code can go here
    })
</script>
```

```html
<form id="uploadForm" action="https://gpstest.surveybook.net/upload/upload.cgi" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file_upload">Select a file:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" onchange="uploadFile()"><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove $(document).ready , You don't need that here

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="https://gpstest.surveybook.net/upload/upload.cgi" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file_upload">Select a file:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" onchange="uploadFile()"><br>
</form>

<script>
    function uploadFile() {
        alert('You are in uploadFile!');
        // Get the form element
        var form = document.getElementById('uploadForm');

        // Submit the form
        form.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I use the code that you write.
When i select file , i see the message that says "You are in upload file" but in console it says "Uncaught TypeError: form is null" .

Comment: Here is the link if you want to look at it :
https://gpstest.surveybook.net/login.html

Answer (score -1):

You're encountering an issue because you're defining a function after the DOM has loaded. Here, you have two options for updating your script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Other codes
})
function uploadFile(){
    // Get the form element
    var form = document.getElementById('uploadForm');
        
    // Submit the form
    form.submit();
}
```

or

```
var uploadFile;
$(document).ready(function(){
    uploadFile = function(){
        // Get the form element
        var form = document.getElementById('uploadForm');
        
        // Submit the form
        form.submit();
    }
})
```